PHPWORD text writing sequence
I received a request to write a paragraph of Chinese text into word. The direction of word text should be vertical and fill from the right to the left. I looked at the current documentation, there are no relevant examples, do not know how to implement.
I looked at the documentation and found that I could use setBreakType and setColsNum to achieve vertical rows, but not right-to-left rows
